# Proving that a functional is unbounded from above and from below

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-analysis

Consider the following functional $F: H_0^1(\Omega) \times H^2 (\Omega)$ given by 
$$
F(u, \varphi) = \frac 12 \int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2 \ dx + \frac 12 \int_\Omega q(\varphi + \chi)u^2 \ dx - \frac 14 \int_\Omega (\Delta \varphi)^2 \ dx - \frac 14 \int_\Omega |\nabla \varphi|^2 \ dx - \frac{\alpha}{2|\Omega|}\int_\Omega\varphi \ dx  
$$
where $q \in C(\overline \Omega)$ and $\chi$ is of class $C^2$ in $\Omega$. Consider the restriction of the functional to the set $M \times \tilde V$, where
$$
M = \left\{u \in H_0^1(\Omega) \ : \  \int_\Omega u^2 \ dx - 1 = \int_\Omega qu^2 \ dx - \alpha  = 0\right\}
$$
and
$$
\tilde V = \left\{ \varphi \in H^2 (\Omega) \ : \ \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial n} = 0  \text{ on } \partial \Omega \text{ and } \int_\Omega \varphi = 0 \right\}.
$$

> How to show that this functional is unbounded from above and from
>   below on $M \times \tilde V$?

Comment: If $q\equiv 1$ and $\alpha\neq 1$, then $M=\emptyset$.